# Weird glibc error with writing out a file

Tags: c++, glibc

I'm getting a strange error:

```
*** glibc detected *** findbasis: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000006a32ce0 ***
```

When I try to close() a std::ofstream:

```
void writeEvectors(int l, parameters params, PetscReal* evectors, int basis_size)
{
    for (int n = 1 + l; n <= params.nmax(); n++)
    {
        std::stringstream fname(std::ios::out);
        fname << params.getBasisFunctionFolder() << "/evectors_n" << std::setw(4) << std::setfill('0') << n << "_l" << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << l;
        std::ofstream out(fname.str().c_str(), std::ios::binary);
        std::cerr << "write out file:" << fname.str() << " ...";
        out.write((char*)( evectors + n * basis_size),sizeof(PetscReal) * basis_size);
        std::cerr << "done1" << std::endl;
        if (out.fail() || out.bad())
            std::cerr << "bad or fail..." << std::endl;
        out.close();
        std::cerr << "done2" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "done writing out all evectors?" << std::endl;
}
```

When run, this program never reaches the "done2" (or the "bad or fail..."), however the "done1" is reached.  Also, the data that *is* written out is good (as in what I expect).

I'm honestly at a loss as to why this happens, I can't think of any reason "close()" would fail.

Thanks for any help.

(I'm beginning to think it is some sort of compiler bug/error.  I'm running GCC 4.1.2 (!) (RHEL 5 I believe) through mpicxx)

Comment: Errors from `malloc` or `free` are usually detected well after they actually occurred (if at all; they may simply segfault); use something like valgrind to find out where the actual invalid access occurred that trashed the free block list.

Comment: Hmm. Looks suspiciously like a memory-related problem (e.g. accidentally overwriting someone else's memory). Are you *sure* `evectors + n * basis_size` is doing what you want? I would have thought something like `(char*)(evectors + n) + (char*)(n * basis_size)` or just `(char*)(evectors + n)` would be correct judging from your size argument.

Comment: Cameron:  It is actually a `basis_size x basis_size` array, stored as a 1d array.  I had to roll my own lapack wrapper, and this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: thanks geekosaur, as it turns out, it was way before this... the only weird thing is that it kept happening at the exact same place in the code (I would think that the detection would be somewhat stochastic, but I guess not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glibc error sounds like there's a problem with freeing memory. If you run inside Valgrind, a free memory profiler, it ought to give you a more helpful explanation of the error.

Running in Valgrind is fairly painless - just compile the executable with the -g option to add debugging flags (assuming you're using the GNU compiler) and then in your Linux terminal enter `valgrind ./your_executable` and see what happens.